# curve() using a function with argument in R

Tags: r, function, plot, curve

```
ppt=function(v, tail = 0.5){
  if (tail == 1){
    6/pi^2/v^2
  } else {
    if (v < 11) {
      (1-tail)*(11-v)/55
      } else {tail*6/pi^2/(v-10)^2}
  }
}
curve(ppt(tail = 0.2))
Error in curve(ppt(tail = 0.2)) : 
  'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

How should I plot a smooth curve for the function ppt() with different values of variable tail?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `curve(ppt(x,tail = 0.2))` because `x` is a special variable for `curve` but you'll still have a problem with your function because you are usign `if()` the function is not properly vectorized. It needs to return a vector when pass a vector via `v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following trick?

```
w = 0.2
g <- function(z) ppt(z, tail = w)
curve(g)
```

And do not forget to replace, as @MrFlick points out in the comment:

```
if (v < 11) {
      (1-tail)*(11-v)/55
      } else {tail*6/pi^2/(v-10)^2}
```

by

```
ifelse(v < 11, (1-tail)*(11-v)/55, tail*6/pi^2/(v-10)^2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Either (1) rewrite ppt to vectorize it (not shown) or else (2) use Vectorize as shown below in which case ppt does not have to be modified.  Also use this syntax.

```
curve(Vectorize(ppt)(x, tail = 0.2), ylab = "ppt")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. I wish I could mark two answers but unfortunately, only one is allowed. I marked the other one because it solves my situation as well and it came first. Thanks again.